# Cutting an image from a specific place

Tags: android, imageview, image-scaling

I have the following row items inside my horizontal recyclerview -

[image]

As you can see, the items I get from the server are wide. What I want is to cut the image width by some value, but I want the cut to take place from where the line starts until the right end of the image.

Here is my XML -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="303dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/search_image_contact_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/vendorImageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The original image I get from the server is 303DP, and I need to cut that in half - starting the cut from where the line I drew starts and not from where the image actually starts.

How can I achieve this behavior?